# My blower motor doesn't have the brown wires for a capacitor

Tags: furnace

My blower motor only has 3 wires and there's no wires for a capacitor

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need a lot more information before we can help you (e.g. make and model number, picture, wiring diagram, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a shaded pole motor or perhaps a variable speed motor. If It doesn’t have wires for a capacitor it doesn’t need a capacitor. Capacitors are only for split phase motors. Granted split phase motors are most common for blowers but by no means the only motors for blowers.